# Not able to run test on HTMLUNIT DRIVER

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, htmlunit-driver

I am writing automation scripts in selenium webdriver and want to test it on headless browser. When I tried HTMLUNITDRIVER, the test doesn't even start. I couldn't find out the step where script was not working. The same script runs successfully on firefox. I am using htmlunit driver 2.20 , selenium 2.53 and FF 45.0.2. Please advise.

Comment: Please use latest [2.27](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/)

Comment: You need to provide your complete case, so other can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I upgraded HTML Unit driver version to 2.27, but still test is not running.I tried running the same test on selenium standalone server 2.52 jar as it has inbuilt htmlunitdriver jars, but it also didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Download 2.31.0 version of HTMLUnitDriver jar from below link and check. Link: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases